# How to make a circle around content using CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Like this

[image: circle around content]

With only this code

```
<span>1</span>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840736/easier-way-to-create-circle-div-than-using-an-image

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to CSS a number to be surrounded by a circle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861224/how-to-css-a-number-to-be-surrounded-by-a-circle)

Comment: You have written “ellipse” but show an image with a circle. Which one do you mean?

Comment: Use CSS `-moz-border-radius: 50%;border-radius: 30px;`

Comment: Check out my latest improvement on how to make a circle resize to fit all the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create three vertical dots (ellipsis) inside a circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40628465/create-three-vertical-dots-ellipsis-inside-a-circle)

Answer (score 134):

http://jsfiddle.net/MafjT/

You can use this css

```
span {
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;

    -moz-border-radius: 30px; /* or 50% */
    border-radius: 30px; /* or 50% */

    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Because you want a circle, you need to set the same value to width, height and line-height (to center the text vertically). You also need to use half of that value to the border radius.

This solution always renders a circle, regardless of content length.

---

But, if you want an ellipse that expands with the content, then http://jsfiddle.net/MafjT/256/

---

## Resize with content - Improvement

In this **https://jsfiddle.net/36m7796q/2/** you can see how to render a circle that reacts to a change in content length.
You can even edit the content on the last circle, to see how the diameter changes.

Comment: Adding: **pure css info icon** to be found easier by SE. I searched a while and finally found your great css solution when searching "css text around circle"...

Comment: It doesn't work for inline elements such as `Click on <span>i</span> for info` where `display:block` has been changed to `display:inline` so that it can flow as part of the text. Any idea how to work with this?

Comment: The last example (https://jsfiddle.net/36m7796q/2/) doesn't render correctly in Firefox 50 for me. I get an oval shape rather than a circle.

Comment: @leeb Replace the `display: inline-flex` with `display: inline-block` in Firefox. This fixes the problem but causes the text not to be vertically centered.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos yes this works, but as you say it does not result in the exact same result. I've come to the conclusion that the best way is to use a fixed width/height element, and hope the content isn't too long ;)

Answer (score 6):

Using CSS3:

```
span
{-moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
border-color:black;
    background-color:black;
color:white;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    font-size:1.3em;
}
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/NXZnq/

Comment: This did not render as a circle in my case but more like rounded left and right and flat top and bottom. Your html may vary.

Answer (score 6):

You have many answers now but I try tell you the basics.

First  element is inline element so giving it margin from top we need to convert it to block element. I converted to inline-block because its close to inline and have features of block elements.

Second, you need to giving padding right and left more than top and bottom because numerals itself extend from top to bottom so it gets reasonable height BUT as we want to make the span ROUND so we give them padding more on left and right to make room for BORDER RADIUS.

Third, you set border-radius which should be more than PADDING + width of content itself so around 27px you will get required roundness but for safely covering all numerals you can set it to some higher value.

[Practical Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zVHK7/).

Answer (score 5):

The border-radius shorthand property can be used to define all four corners simultaneously. The property accepts either one or two sets of values, each consisting of one to four lengths or percentages.

The Syntax:

```
[ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} [ / [ <length> | <percentage> ]{1,4} ]?
```

Examples:

```
border-radius: 5px 10px 5px 10px / 10px 5px 10px 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px 10px / 10px;
```

**I your case**

```
span {
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #000;
    color : white;
    padding : 10px 15px;


}
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/daWcc/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other solutions, http://css3pie.com/ does a great job as a polyfill for old internet explorer versions

EDIT: not necessary as of 2016

Comment: Hey downvoter, this answer is nearly 3 years old - it worked very well at the time and still does for legacy browsers

Comment: Depends on the question       :-)

Comment: It's not *still* wrong, it *became* wrong over time with changing context. Actually I wondered if there's a meta post about that theme? It may hurt, but I agree it's a good thing if you can lose points if your (in this case, my) answer outdates - that contributes to the health of SO.