# HTML Text wrap round box

Tags: html, css

I want to create a circle on an HTML page with text in it. Something similar to this:
https://jsfiddle.net/f5vctpth/1/

I now used the img-round class from bootstrap to do it, but it is not dynamic...

```
<div class="img-circle">
```

Is there a way to dynamically wrap the text in the div?

I found this: (but havent yet found a way to make it work.)

http://webplatform.adobe.com/Demo-for-Alice-s-Adventures-in-Wonderland/

Comment: you need to hide text out from div???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text within circle div. Div size adjusted to content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169806/text-within-circle-div-div-size-adjusted-to-content)

Answer (score 1):

try this  fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f5vctpth/2/

add this to your div `overflow: hidden;` it will work

```
           <div class="img-circle" style="
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                background: #333;
                color: red;
                text-align: center;
            ">
```

in above style you missed `overflow: hidden;` add this to your style `overflow: hidden;`

replace with this code it will work

```
           <div class="img-circle" style="
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                background: #333;
                color: red;
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;
            ">
```