# Responsive circle with centered content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

Is there a way to make the following:

```css
#id {
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

A **round `div` with the text centered vertically and horizontally**. At the same time keeping the circle responsive.
By that I mean having a `width` of say `50%` of the containing `div`, at the same time keeping the `height` percentage equal as to make a circle.

And changing the static `100px` to pertentages makes the circle oval.

Comment: You could use the `vw` or `vh` unit, if you can proportion it. [An example](https://jsfiddle.net/b5ye1ar1/)

Comment: @Paulie_D I don't think this question can be closed as a dupe of the aspect ratio question. The approach to make the circle is the same but it doesn't seem close enough to be a dupe (content centering and the fact it is a circle).

Comment: The answers are exactly the same, padding ratio and viewport units. **Simply a dupe**...*anything else is just border-radius and layout.*

Comment: @Paulie_D it is the aspect ratio combined with the "anything else" part that I believe makes this question worth keeping. I don't think someone looking for a responsive circle with centered content would find a suitable answer in the aspect ratio question or in the content centering one alone.

Comment: After 2 years, here is one [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359039/607874) that demonstrates a responsive circle that adapts to content length (see the last link under "Resize with content - Improvement")

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Viewport Units

If you use the same viewport unit (either `vw` or `vh`) then you should get a responsive circle.

A viewport unit of `100` would be 100% of either the width or height. Therefore it is very similar to using a percentage.

```css
div {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 22):

You can make a **circle with centered content** with:

- `padding-bottom` to keep the aspect ratio of the circle according to it's width ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10441480/1811992))
- `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);` with absolute positioning to center the content verticaly and horizontaly in the circle (see approach 1 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25799339/1811992))

```css
.circle{
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  padding-bottom:50%;
  background:gold;
  border-radius:50%;
}
.circle h3{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

*Note that you will need to add vendor prefixes to the transform property to maximize browser support (see [canIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) for more info).*

Answer (score 6):

```
.circle {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS has the `aspect-ratio` property for this, which applies on width and height of the element.

More for **web**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

More for **react native**: https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#aspectratio

Answer (score 0):

The `@media` rule is used in media queries to apply different styles/size/width/height for different media types/devices.

Media queries can be used to check many things, such as:

width and height of the viewport
width and height of the device
orientation (is the tablet/phone in landscape or portrait mode?)
resolution

See below example:

```css
    /* Mobile & small screen size devices*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .circle {
            width: 210px!important;
            height: 210px!important;
        }
    }

    /* Desktop, Laptop, Tablet */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
        .circle {
            width: 356px;
            height: 356px;
        }
    }

    .circle {
        margin: auto;
        width: 356px;
        height: 356px;
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```