# how to change the shape of submit button to circle

Tags: html, css, button, submit, submit-button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw Circle using css alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone)

I would like to know if there is any way to change the shape of the submit button from rectangle to circular shape??

**I dont want to use an circular shapped image solution.** I want the all other characteristics of the button as from the css style.

Comment: @WesleyMurch but that question shows how to create a circle shapped div area.. mine to change submit buttons shape..

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't find it useful. If it helps, styling a submit button is very much like styling a div (try it). In fact the highest voted answers on both questions are the same. I didn't expect your question would actually be closed, someone must have flagged it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is already answered but I recommend you [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap).

It is a HTML/CSS framework which allows you make [great buttons](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) (among others) easily.

This buttons are "crossbrowser" which means they are compatible with Internet Explorer.

With only one class - `btn` - you can stylize a `<button>`, `<input type="button">` or `<a>`.

This :

```
<button class="btn"></button>
```

Gives that:

[image]

You also can customize your button quickly with an optional class :

`btn-primary`, `btn-info`, `btn-success`, `btn-warning`, `btn-danger` and `btn-inverse`.

This classes transform your button like that :

[image]

Then you can choose a size with the classes `btn-large`, `btn-small` and `btn-mini`.

Finally, you can add an icon ([the list is here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons)) in your button.

This:

```
<button class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>
    <span>Checkout</span>
</button>
```

Gives that:

[image]

Have fun with your new buttons. `:)`

Comment: I was working on the same.. but that doesnt has any options for button shape.. do they?

Comment: It offers a default shape (like in the pictures above) but you are free to modify it: **it's just CSS!** Modify `border-radius: 5px` in `border-radius: 10px` if you need it. `:)`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 14):

Use [`border-radius`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp) property.

Example:

```css
.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 50%
}
```

The above example will give you a regular circle.
If you want just a little rounded shape, try this:

```css
.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 5px
}
```

**Live demo: [Regular circle](http://tinkerbin.com/r5WPt7ie)

Live demo: [Rounded shape](http://tinkerbin.com/Bx7el0AE)

Live demo: [Input button with text](http://tinkerbin.com/S8BAZK3Q)**

Comment: But this solution doesnt retain the characteristics of "submit" button.. It just creates a div in circular shape..

Comment: @vivek_jonam See this: http://tinkerbin.com/8wU6CMgy

Comment: but that is also a div area.. i need it to have submit button properties..

Comment: @vivek_jonam Just replace `div` with `input`. Example: http://tinkerbin.com/S8BAZK3Q

Comment: Links to live demo are dead.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS border radius.  I would recommend googling 'CSS button generator' or such and finding any number of button generating tools that you can play around with to get the css right. You would just need to make sure the element's height=width and then adjust the corner radii accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this style:

```
input[type='submit'] {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-radius in your CSS but it won't be supported in IE.

Play around with:-

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to either use the Jquery UI (you can make you own theme)
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

or

CSS3
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons

CSS3 will not work in IE.