# What is the simplest and most universal way of doing a CSS circle?

Tags: html, css

what is the simplest and most universal way of transforming a div with these css propperties into a perfect circle?

```
div {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5em;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw Circle using css alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone)

Comment: There are several older questions about drawing a CSS circle, with good answers. Asking which way is the simplest and most universal is primarily opinion-based. (Simplicity is relative to what you regard as simple.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The css rule to make a circle out of an HTML element is:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

To make it work in all browsers additionally use:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
```

Take a [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e8whefhs/1)

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -o-border-radius: 50%;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```