# How to draw a circle in html

Tags: html, geometry

Hy, I wish to draw a circle in a html page, unfortunately I cannot use css3 stuff like: border-radius, is there any more basic other way without html5 or css3? thx!

Comment: Why you cannot use CSS3?

Comment: Create a circle image, and import it with `<img>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone

Comment: Do you actually want to 'draw' a circle or do you just want to display one somewhere? What size circle and to what end?

Answer (score 1):

In order of complexity, here are your options:-

1)  Use the <IMG> element to link to and display an image of a circle
2)  Use CSS to create one (I know you've already said you can't do this)
3)  Use the CANVAS element and Javascript to draw a circle in the element
4)  You could also use SVG and (again) Javascript to do this - or you could use a javascript library like Raphael to achieve this.

Without using "HTML5", CSS or JS however, I'd say the only remaining option is #1.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone which would be much more flexible than an image

Comment: Yes, but the user has already said they won't be using CSS.

Comment: `I cannot use **css3** stuff ...`

Answer (score 0):

this called circle

```css
.circle{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```