# Getting this effect without putting img into css

Tags: html

[image]

I want to achieve the look and feel as shown in the above picture. There is a completed image besides two lines of text. I know how to achieve this via putting image into background of css. But I am working in a Salesforce project and it is really hard to put images into css. So is there any pure html way in order to achieve this (the fonts and size are definitely css though). I have tried a lot but none succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

The html code for a checkmark is **& # 10003;** and a heavy checkmark is **& # 10004;** (without the spaces).

Create a `div` around the checkmark and make it a circle:  [Draw Circle using css alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone)

...Otherwise you are stuck using a ballot-box checkmark:  ☑  (**& # 9745;**)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. And sorry I might haven't made my question clear. I mean, I can use the image, but in an html way - not putting it into css file. Add a html img tag is fine to my scenario.