# Create round corner image by CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to create image avatar like avatar contact of skype,can you help me ?, I try use border `radius-border` but lucky

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you add a sketch of what you want? And please add the code that you've tried so far. Please note that the correct syntax is `border-radius`.

Comment: it's not radius-border is `border-radius`

Comment: Do you mean this? [**See demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8u4koa1s/).

Comment: you may want to read up on [Draw Circle using css alone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936972/draw-circle-using-css-alone)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `border-radius` on `img` tags, too.

```css
img{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3016/3071708735_ddaf5d361b.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: You are right :), post edited

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```css
.circleImage {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green;
}

HTML:
```

```html
<div class="circleImage"></div>
```

Keep the border radius half of the width or height for circular images like in Skype.

Comment: or just use 50% as your declaration. Please also note, the border radius property no longer requires prefixing. :)

Comment: .....will upvote(+1) after the border radius edit ;-)

Comment: Removed the prefixes and also made it 50%. :) Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/unqsr8ky/2/)**

```
div.avatar {
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
div.avatar img {   
    height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://www.stockazoo.com/uploads/3/5/4/5/3545172/5579090_orig.jpg" />
</div>
```